# Can this sentence work without 'that'? If yes, why?

Tags: sentence-patterns

And given (that) the Nord wasn't a thing when the 8-series was launched, we could see the OnePlus 9 phones get pricier than that.

Comment: I think it works better with "that".

Answer (score -1):

It works fine without "that". I'm not sure why, but I suspect it's a more informal way of saying the same thing.

Comment: You need to provide sources for your answer.